# Regular expression with (?:

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expression and trying to find out what this means.

```
(?:(?:^KC[\\x00-\\xff]{50}))
```

Upon looking up online, ?: means no backtrace, I am not sure what that means?
Also from ^ , does that mean a line that does not contain "KC...." for 50 character long?

Comment: `(?:` is the start of a non-capturing group, but the regex you've shown is invalid.

Comment: Oops, i didint finish the regx, i simply added end of ).  But, what does it mean when you say non-capturing group?  thanks.

Comment: It means that it doesn't get added to the groups collection in the match, so you can't use it in a replacement expression

Comment: The double `(?:` still makes no sense. It's syntactically valid, but useless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non capturing group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use brackets `()` in regex, you can use references (`\1`..`\9`) to captured groups further in the regex. Example: `(a|b)_\1` will match `'a_a'` and `'b_b'`.

`?:` means that the captured group won't have a number (actually, it's better to say that it won't be captured, it's just a group).

`^` means negation in character classes (in `[]`). Outside `[]` it means beginning of the line.